# How to make a block explorer?

Tags: blockchain

I need to make a block explorer for some alternative cryptocurrencies. I'm using Litecoin for testing, but JSON-RPC requests through PHP are [very slow](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/too-slow-json-rpc). Maybe JSON-RPC isn't the right thing for such purposes? What other tools you can recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Index the blockchain in a database and keep the database that has the blockchain updated as blocks come in, you would be essentially running a modified node that's really good at keeping data.